# Javascript onbeforeunload Error with Jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have submit button submit_marksheets, which submits marks before that It will ask for confirmation.

I have one more thing is whenever changes made and user will click to another page then It will ask for "save changes" confirmation.

These codes I have given below. The problem is When I click on submit marksheets button it will gives warning. But after I click on other pages the onbefore unload is not invoking. I dont know why.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

```
$(':input', document.frmMarksheets).live("change", function() {
    $('#submit_marksheets').live('click', function() {
        setConfirmUnload(false);
        return true;
    });
    setConfirmUnload(true);
});

function setConfirmUnload(on) {
     window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
}
```

Comment: Is `unloadMessage` a string or a function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the reason for the problem in the code you have, but  have had troubles with this sort of unload confirmation and this is the route I took:

Set a global variable that is your indicator whether or not to issue a message:

```
var ConfirmPageExit = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return (ConfirmPageExit) ? unloadMessage : null;  };
```

Now, any atempt to exit will fire your message. Then, on anything you want to use to shut off the message, just set that var to false:

```
$('#submit_marksheets').live('click', function() {
    ConfirmPageExit = false;
});
```